# Methods for Validating Payloads in Azure Data Explorer Update Policies

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm working with Azure Data Explorer and trying to move data from one table to another using a kusto-function set as the update policy. I need to validate the payload with multiple “where” statements. How can I handle and monitor payloads which do not meet the validation criteria effectively?

For context, when I used Azure Functions for transformation steps, I simply introduced some logging for this purpose. Are there similar best practices or tools in Azure Data Explorer that would allow for comfortable payload validation?

Looking forward to some tips. :)

That's how a simplified data structure can look like:

```
{
    Sensor-ID: "123-ABC",
    Sensor-Location: "Station1", 
    PayloadStructureVersion: "v2",
    Value: 13.3,
    Unit: "Voltage",
    Timestamp: "2023-01-01T01:01:00Z"
}
```

For the different sensor-location I already set up different tables where the data will be appended by update policies, which also checks if the data is valid by checking if the sensor-id follows a certain regex pattern, if the payloadStructureVersion is still supported and if the unit matches the sensor (This information is stored in a separate lookup table).

The query performed by the update policy currently looks like this:

```
RawData
    | where ['payload']['Sensor-ID'] matches regex "[0-9]{3}-[A-Z]{3}"
    | where ['payload']['PayloadStructureVersion'] in ("v2","v3")
    | where ['payload']['Sensor-Location'] == "Station1" 
    | extend SensorId = tostring(['payload']['Sensor-ID'])
    | extend PayloadUnit = tostring(['payload']['Unit'])
    | join kind=inner (Sensors) on SensorId, $left.PayloadUnit == $right.Unit
```

But how can I handle all the data which doesn't meet those requirements?

Comment: (1) an update policy doesn't 'move' data - it appends data to another table, when ingesting into the source table; (2) it's not clear what you mean by "validation" - an update policy runs a query over just-ingested records, and appends the results of that query to a different table. it doesn't 'validate' data, but it can filter it, aggregate it, etc. - according to user-defined logic; (3) you may want to clarify what you're trying to achieve, perhaps using an example (e.g. provide a few input records, and clearly explain what you wish to do with them in your update policy's query)

Comment: Yeah, you're absolutely right that data doesn't get moved, but rather queried and appended.
I updated my initial question to hopefully make the whole situation more clear.

Answer (score 0):

> But how can I handle all the data which doesn't meet those requirements?

You can define *another* update policy that filters for the *opposite* conditions, resulting with those being appended to a *different* table.

Then, if you need to retain/process those events, you can do so from *that* table.

Alternatively, if the source table's soft delete period is larger than zero, then you have all of the raw events there, and you can apply similar processing for the specific set of filtered events directly on that table.

Comment: Makes sense and will definitely work. But with this solution, I have to manually check the other tables' size / content regularly, right? Or is there any option to collect some logs for automated monitoring / visualization / alarms?
Since I will have multiple update policies, I'd be helpful to automate as much as possible.

Comment: I don't see why you have to do anything manually. You can use any existing tool or client library for creating the automation you're interested in. Those are documented in the following links: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/tools-integrations-overview; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/